# How to make a bottom arrow hole in a rectangle

Tags: css

I want to change the button on my website.
like this.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqfxZ.png]

But I don't know how to change the bottom style of this button.
I heard we can do this using '::after' or '::before'.

Comment: Kevin Powell explains here how to make same kind of shape. You will find your answer here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY7Rj8aZcZk&t=980s

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is one of the 100 options

```css
.my-special-thing {
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px 30px;
   background-color: orange;
   display: inline-block;
}

.my-special-thing:before {
   position: absolute;
   right: 30px;
   bottom: -10px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   background-color: white;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-special-thing">Post a job</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , this can be achieved using before & after , please check the code below

```css
.Box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F7E6D2;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
.Box::before {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #F4F4F5;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
.Box::after{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="Items">
    <div class="Box">
      <h3>Case</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
```